# Objective-C download image from PHP/MySQL Blob into NSData object?

Tags: php, objective-c, base64, blob, nsdata

I have a MySQL database with a bunch of images stored as blobs.  I can have a PHP script allow download of the images with:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
$image=mysql_result($result,0,"image");
echo base64_encode($logo);
```

Then, I can use an NSURLConnection in objective-c to pull download the image from that PHP script. It provides me an NSData object, but it's storing the base64 string representation of the image, rather than the image.

So, I can convert the NSData to a string with:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:incomingData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then, I'm not sure how to convert the base64 string into an NSData of the original image file.  I suspect, I may even be able to convert it straight from the received NSData object into the NSData of the image that I need.

What is the most simple path to getting the image stored in the NSData object, as if I loaded it straight from a file with:

```
NSData* image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
```

Thank you!

Comment: I found a way to accomplish what I was looking for.  Using NSDataAdditions, I added a category to NSData to get +(NSData*) dataWithBase64EncodedString;  That does the trick, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: You could convert directly from the data instead of a string without much difficulty. Assuming the decoder gets a C string from the string object, you could just use `[incomingData bytes]` and `[incomingData length]` instead. Of course, you could avoid the issue by not base64 encoding in the first place. Is there a reason you can't send the binary data?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw  You are right. I should just use incomingData with a binary transfer.  I had another issue early on that fooled me into believing that this method would not work.  Thank you.  This is a more efficient solution.